# TexStudio Commands on mouse over quickly disappear

Tags: macros, miktex, texstudio

I have installed miktex 32bit and texstudio on my windows 7 32bit laptop.

Whenever I mouseover a command like  `tabular`  in the example

```
\end{tabular}
```

the tooltip shows up for some millisecs and then dissappears... so i cant read it..

what could cause that problem? tell me if u need more information

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Hello, for further clarification: I am talking about these popups: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13720935/texstudio.jpg which appears when I mouse over a command. But they only appear for less than 1/5 seconds. (It was hard to get this screenshot!) How can I make them lasting?

Answer (score 1):

It comes from an option to show the help as tool tip. You can enable/disable it using the **Configure** on the **Options** menu.

See below. Active the **Advanced options** on the left and check the **Special options** part on the right.

I'm using TeXStudio on Linux and it works here but the tip appears when I stop the cursor over the command and it is shown until I move the mouse.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. You describe well how it is supposed to work. But on both my computers (one win7 32bit the other win8 64bit) it just shows up for a brief moment and then disappears again (of course im not moving the mouse at all) Can someone confirm this "bug"?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved when I uncheck "Zeige Vorschau als Tooltip auf Text im Editor" guess it translates to "Show preview as tooltip on text in editor" (or formula as in the screenshot from Sigur)

But I guess as a trade off I'll miss that function now.. whatever it did.